# Is it possible to utilise partial application in Dart (partial / apply / fixing arguments)

Tags: functional-programming, dart, partial-application

From a function with multiple parameters can we partially apply just one or two parameters to it returning a new function that takes the remaining parameters?

Javascript example using Ramda

```
function buildUri (scheme, domain, path) {
  return `${scheme}://${domain}/${path}`
}

const buildHttpsUri = R.partial(buildUri, ['https']);

const twitterFavicon = buildHttpsUri('twitter.com', 'favicon.ico');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just forward to another function

```
String buildUri (String scheme, String domain, String path) {
  return `${scheme}://${domain}/${path}`
}

String buildHttpsUri(String domain, String path) => buildUri('https', domain, path);
```